# GWT ImageCell: Change image dynamically in a DataGrid or CellTable

Tags: gwt

I have DataGrid where one on of the columns contains images. I used this code to generate the column.

```
Column<Job, String> expandHideColumn = new Column<Job, String>(
                imageCell) {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Job object) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void render(Context context, Job Object, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img src='images/expand.jpeg' style='cursor: pointer' />");
            }
}
```

What I want is on clicking the image it has to change. For this I added a click handler on the ImageCell like this

```
ImageCell imageCell = new ImageCell() {

            @Override
            public Set<String> getConsumedEvents() {
                Set<String> events = new HashSet<String>();
                events.add("click");
                return events;
            }
};
```

In the onBrowserEvent method I wrote this

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element element,
        Job job, NativeEvent event) {
    if (element.getFirstChildElement().isOrHasChild(
            Element.as(event.getEventTarget()))) {
        if (element.getFirstChildElement().getPropertyString("src")
                .matches("(.*)expand.jpeg")) {
            element.getFirstChildElement().setPropertyString("src",
                    "images/collapse.jpeg");

        } else {
            element.getFirstChildElement().setPropertyString("src",
                    "images/expand.jpeg");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is a good approach to change images on click event. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a column value for know the state of the column :

```
Column<Job, Boolean> expandHideColumn = new Column<Job, Boolean>(new ImageExpandCollapseCell()) {

   @Override
   public Boolean getValue(Job object) {
      return object.isExpand(); //The object know the expand state ?
   }
}
expandHideColumn.setValueUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Job, Boolean>() {
   void update(int index, Job object, Boolean value) {
     object.setExpand(value);
   }
});
```

The ImageExpandCollapseCell look like this :

```
public class ImageExpandCollapseCell extends AbstractCell<Boolean> {
  final String EXPAND = "images/expand.jpeg";
  final String COLLAPSE = "images/collapse.jpeg";

  interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<div style=\"float:right\"><img src=\"" + url + "\"></div>")
    SafeHtml img(String url);
  }

  private static Template template;

  /**
   * Construct a new ImageCell.
   */
  public ImageCell() {
    super("click"); //Replace your getConsumedEvents()
    if (template == null) {
      template = GWT.create(Template.class);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, Boolean value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {

      sb.append(template.img(UriUtils.fromSafeConstant(value ? EXPAND : COLLAPSE)));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element element,
          Boolean value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Boolean> valueUpdater) {
     valueUpdate.update(!value);
  }
}
```

I improve the proposed version of [user905374](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905374/user905374)
It's not a good idea to instantiate new value in the render method.

The column render method call the Cell render method, you musn't replace it !

With the FieldUpdater, you can change the state of the image : expand or collapse and update the cell display (it will be rendered again).